# How to find a sequence of digits and multiply those sequence of digits with number 2 in JAVA?

Tags: java

How to find a sequence of digits and multiply only those sequence of digits with number 2 in JAVA?

Let's say I have a string "My age is 19". How do I get a string "My age is 38" as the output?

Also, how do I reverse that multiplied number in the string later on. For above example input, the second output should be "My age is 83"

I tried using java.util.regex.Pattern. It works. However, is there any other way we can do that. Probably through converting the string into an array? I tried. But I am struck at multiplying sequence of characters in the string. Instead I am able to multiple each digit. But I want the sequence of digits to be multiplied by 2. For instance, in above example, I am able to multiply each digit 1 and 9 by 2. But I want 19 as a 2 digit number to be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Please show us what you have done already ... so that we can understand what part of the problem is giving you difficulty.

Comment: Use the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method: `String yourString = "My age is 20"; String num = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", ""); if (num.matches("\\d+")) { yourString = yourString.replaceAll(num, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(num) * 2)); } System.out.println(yourString);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are saying multiplying the whole string **"My age is 20"** by 2. If so, there is no way to achieve your desired output.

What you can do is, loop over the whole string, find a section which appear to be in numeric form and check for that section. There are several ways to check if a string is digit and some of them are discussed in the following link.

[How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

After that, you can perform multiplication on a (parsed) digit-string then add them back to the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression and do something like this

```
    //set regexp pattern with group representing number
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("My age is (\\d+)");
    //get number from string
    Matcher matcher = new Matcher(pattern, "My age is 20");
    matcher.find();
    int age = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    //multiply
    int result = age * 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
String s = "My age is 19";
String doubled = pat.matcher(s).replaceAll(m -> "" + Integer.valueOf(m.group()) * 2);
System.out.println(doubled);
String reversed = pat.matcher(doubled).replaceAll(m -> new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString());
System.out.println(reversed);
```

output

```
My age is 38
My age is 83
```